# What is returned when your primary key is not unique

Tags: mysql

I'm new to programming. My question is, if you have a primary key that is not unique ( I understand at that point it ceases to be a primary key) then what is returned? Are multiple records returned?

```
EmployeeID  HoursWorked
01          100
01          120
02          75
02          115
03          140
03          80
```

For instance, if you write a query to search for an employee ID of `01`, what will be returned?

Again, I'm really new to all of this so forgive me if it's a stupid question.

Comment: "I understand at that point it ceases to be a primary key" My sense is that you *don't* understand that. There is no primary key here.

Comment: "if you write a query to search for an employee ID of 01, what will be returned?". You'll get a list of all the records which contain 01 in the employee ID column. I think perhaps you maybe need to do some more studying and experimenting with SQL. And yes as strawberry says, a column which contains duplicate values cannot be considered as a primary key. A primary key's values _must_ be unique. If you define a column as being a primary key column, the database engine will enforce that and not allow you to create duplicate entries.

Comment: I give you +1 for your question, since being new means you need help. Sadly in Stack Never mention i'm new. This is a forbidden word. As soon you say I'm new some people give you downvotes. Really sad. You never see this kind of fellows in the Expert Exchange forum.

Comment: There is no such thing as an implicit primary key in sql You have to explicity declare a column as a primary key either as part of a CREATE table or with an ALTER table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do something like

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE EmployeeID = 01;
```

You will get two rows:

```
EmployeeID    HoursWorked
01            100
01            120
```

But normally - if you set up the column as primary key - MySQL **will not allow** you to insert rows which have no unique id.

Answer (score 0):

if you not use `primary key` then duplicate id record can be `inserted`

so if you will get `01` than it will return all record of `01` id in table like `100 and 120`

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the primary is to prevent you inserting two records (lines) with the same primary key or any unique index. It is just impossible you will get an error.

So if you have set a primary key, a select query will return nothing or one line if you specify exactly which value you want. And you will get an error if you try to insert a new record with a key that already exists.

You will have the same kind of behavior with a unique key